# Tax on crypto earned as income but sold later

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

Suppose I do some work as a freelancer in exchange for [Ether](https://docs.ethhub.io/ethereum-basics/what-is-ether/) tokens, but I do not sell them right away. I hold them for a while, but eventually dispose of them within the same UK tax year.

1. Do I have to pay Income Tax and National Insurance based on the market value of the Ether tokens at the time of receiving them, or when I billed the client?
2. I assume I have to pay Capital Gains tax if I sell the tokens later and realise a gain, but how should I calculate my cost basis?

Comment: I think this is correct: For (1) I think it would be at the time of receipt because you were paid that cash and have a txHash to prove it. But you might want to change your tac and let your customer know that you'd want £X worth of ETH on the day of payment. Otherwise you might get nothing - crypto is volatile ! For (2) your cost basis would be the value of GBP of the ETH on day of receipt, again provable by txHash.